# Excel Formula - IF & "X" > 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that I'm using in Excel to determine what the payback of a value is after "X" of months.  But I'd like to modify the formula to display 0 or $0.00 if the result of the formula is less than $0.00

The current formula is
`=C2-(C2*(G2/24))`

But is there a way I can make this so once the value hits 0 or less than 0, it would simply display $0.00

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
=IF(C2-(C2*(G2/24))>0,C2-(C2*(G2/24)),0)
```

to return a 0 result if the result would have otherwise been negative.

Answer (score 3):

For readability's sake you could also use:

```
=MAX(C2-(C2*(G2/24)),0)
```

That presents Excel with two options, the result of the formula or zero, and asks it to display the larger of the two.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check that out.